# How to use readonly property across multiple classes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a read-only property(name) in class1. How can I use this name property in class2?

```
Public Class Class1
ReadOnly Property name() As String
    Get

        Return System.IO.path.GetFileName("C:\Demo\Sample1")

    End Get
End Property
```

Can I directly carry this name variable value into class2? Need suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via an instance of Class1

```
    Public Class Class2

      Sub New()
            Dim o As New Class1
            Dim s As String  = o.Name

      End Sub

   End Class
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx) is something to read on classes.

Comment: Down voter!...he was asking "How can I use this name property in class2??

Comment: I don't think yours will work as you are reaccessing class2.  You need to `new Class1`

Answer (score 3):

You can access this property everywhere where you have a reference to a Object of type `Class1`. So if your `Class2` objects have a reference, they can use it.

For example:

```
Class Class2
    Property cls1 As New Class1

    Function getClass1Name() As String
        Return cls1.Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Another option is to make the property shared, because it's a value that is independent of any instance of `Class1` that makes sense.

Then you can access it without an instance of `Class1` via the class-name:

```
Class Class1
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\Demo\Sample1")
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Class Class2
    Function getClass1Name() As String
        Return Class1.Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: you have to admit Bala R posted that way before you did, regarding the shared property, and you edited it adding that, you should of mentioned his and +1 him.

Comment: @JonH: I would, but first i haven't seen that he was faster and second it seems that he has deleted his answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your Readonly property is still an instance members and cannot be shared without instantiating Class1 and looking at the property definition, it can be `Shared`. You can make your property `Shared` and use it in class2

```
Public Class Class1
Shared Property name() As String
    Get

        Return System.IO.path.GetFileName("C:\Demo\Sample1")

    End Get
End Property
```

and in class2, you can call

```
Dim class1Name = Class1.name
```

Comment: +1 not sure why you had deleted your original post you had it faster in and it was correct.

Comment: @JonH didn't seem like the OP was interested in having a Shared member but after seeing the discussion below, I thought I'd leave it out there for reference.